# Given a large dataset, how do you remove outliers using IQR method using R

Tags: r, outliers, iqr

We have been given a large dataset, and we are being asked to remove outliers using the IQR method using R.

The data has 53 columns, 17 of which are continuous, the remaining are categorical. How would you use the IQR method to remove outliers to multiple columns, and update the data frame?

I found this function online, but it does not account for columns that have categorical values.

```
sample_data <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 0),
                           y=c(4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 5, 0),
                           z=c(1, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 0, 8, 7, 2, 3))
print("Display original dataframe")
print(sample_data)

detect_outlier <- function(x) {
  
  # calculate first quantile
  Quantile1 <- quantile(x, probs=.25)
  
  # calculate third quantile
  Quantile3 <- quantile(x, probs=.75)
  
  # calculate inter quartile range
  IQR = Quantile3-Quantile1
  
  # return true or false
  x > Quantile3 + (IQR*1.5) | x < Quantile1 - (IQR*1.5)
}

# create remove outlier function
remove_outlier <- function(dataframe,
                           columns=names(dataframe)) {
  
  # for loop to traverse in columns vector
  for (col in columns) {
    
    # remove observation if it satisfies outlier function
    dataframe <- dataframe[!detect_outlier(dataframe[[col]]), ]
  }
  
  # return dataframe
  print("Remove outliers")
  print(dataframe)
}

remove_outlier(sample_data, c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w'))




########these are all my variables

'car.deliver.airport.num','car.deliver.hotel.num','car.deliver.train.station.num','car.displayed.turo.review.num',  'car.displayed.turo.review.num.past.12m','car.displayed.turo.review.num.past.18m','car.displayed.turo.review.num.past.6m','car.displayed.user.review.num','car.displayed.user.review.num.past.12m','car.displayed.user.review.num.past.18m','car.displayed.user.review.num.past.6m','car.extra.mile.fee','car.extra.num','car.extra.phone.mount','car.extra.portable.gps','car.extra.post.trip.cleaning','car.extra.prepaid.ev.recharge','car.extra.prepaid.refuel','car.extra.stroller','car.extra.unlimited.mileage','car.faq.num','car.instant.book','car.insurance','car.miles.included','car.photo.num','car.trip.price','host.car.num'



Original output
#Output after
#   x y z
#1  1 4 1
#2  2 3 3
#3  3 5 2
#4  4 7 9
#5  3 8 8
#6  2 5 7
#7  3 9 0
#8  4 7 8
#9  4 6 7
#10 5 5 2
#11 0 0 3

#Output after
#   x y z
#1  1 4 1
#2  2 3 3
#3  3 5 2
#4  4 7 9
#5  3 8 8
#6  2 5 7
#7  3 9 0
#8  4 7 8
#9  4 6 7
#10 5 5 2
```

I'm expecting for outliers to be removed from the original dataframe, for only continuous variables.

Comment: @akrun just added an example.. the example works, but my actual dataset is way bigger. i included all the variables. some are continuous, some are categorical.

Comment: When you loop, before doing anything else, check that col is numeric ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen how would i check if the col is numeric?

Answer (score 0):

We may do this easily in `tidyverse` i.e. loop `across` the columns that are numeric (`where(is.numeric)`) and `replace` the values that are outliers by applying the `detect_outlier` to `NA`).  Removing the values results in length difference across columns and then it can be saved only as a `list` as `data.frame/tibble` requires all columns to be of same length

```
library(dplyr)
sample_data %>% 
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace(.x, detect_outlier(.x), NA)))
```

Comment: thank you! but we are actually supposed to use the IQR method per prof directions

Comment: @dataanalyst if the column name is `prof`, then `sample_data %>% group_by(prof) %>%  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace(.x, detect_outlier(.x), NA))) %>% ungroup`

Answer (score 0):

First select only the numeric columns, here a simple example:

```r
DF <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=sample(1:100,10),
                 z=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:2],10,replace=TRUE)))

select <- sapply(DF, is.numeric, simplify=TRUE) 

DF2 <- DF[, select, drop=FALSE]
```

Then applying the function removing outliers ...

Comment: Ohh Thank you! this works, however, some of the categories are numerical, like 0 = True, 1 = False. What if I referenced an excel doc that had the variables differentiated, how can i make that adjustment to your code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand ... you mean some numerical cols are really representing boolean?

Comment: yes, exactly, some numerical columns are representing a boolean

Comment: That a numerical column **represents** non-numerical values cannot be detected programmatically! So just add a variable , say repno, that contains FALSE for this columns and do something like `select <- select & repno`

Answer (score 0):

First I have modified your function, replace outliers with NA and allow modifying the IQR times

```
detect_outlier <- function(x,iqtimes=1.5) {
  # calculate first quantile
  Quantile1 <- quantile(x, probs=.25, na.rm = T)
  # calculate third quantile
  Quantile3 <- quantile(x, probs=.75, na.rm = T)
  # calculate inter quartile range
  IQR = Quantile3-Quantile1
  # return true or false
  outiers <- x > Quantile3 + (IQR*iqtimes) | x < Quantile1 - (IQR*iqtimes)
  x[which(outiers)] <- NA
  return(x)
}
```

Select which columns to process (numeric data)

```
cols_to_clean <- names(sample_data )[sapply(sample_data , is.numeric)]
```

Finally apply the function to the data frame.

```
data_clean<- sample_data %>%
  mutate(across(cols_to_clean , ~detect_outlier(.,iqtimes=1.5)))
```